# Reopen previous browser w/tabs in Chrome (*not* most recently closed one)

Tags: google-chrome, history

I had to reboot my Windows 7 box, and had two Chrome browsers open, each with about 10 tabs.  When my box restarted, the last tab set I closed reopened when Chrome came up, but when I opened another Chrome browser the same set was the only on in the "recently closed" selection at the bottom right (Chrome version 20.0.1132.47)

Is there a way to reopen that older tab set in Chrome, some history section I can look at?  I have no recollection about the individual tabs in the browser window.

Comment: In this very case I'm unsure how to find the tabs (without a chrome extension) other than to try to recall them from history. However, in case of having closed one main window you use repeatedly by mistake (before closing chrome via another window); scroll in the history to when you last started a session with the needed window; you'll find the window's tabs opened in sequence with little-to-no time delay in between (since they all opened at the same time last launch). That was my problem when I saw this question, hope it’s helpful if someone’s having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're quite a few [session manager extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/session%20manager) available. Pick the one you like the most.

However, Chrome usually remembers about a dozen recently closed instances (tabs or windows). I personally have had to close multiple windows with multiple tabs in them and restored them right after the restart. The windows showed up in the Recently Closed menu as "X tabs" with a folder icon next to it. If your instance of Chrome didn't act that way, it could've been simply a glitch.

Comment: I wish it had remembered mine...thanks for the extensions link.